# Can you determine the call convention of a compiled function?

Tags: binary, elf, portable-executable, calling-convention

From looking at an executable, is there generally any information in the executable file that relates to the calling convention of the functions inside it?
If so, could you provide an example for the PE or ELF file format specifically?

Comment: In the case of Portable Executable, there isn't any information in the format because the OS and processor doesn't need that information.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you @SemihArtan . That makes total sense. And when you compile c/c++ files you mention the calling convention of the called functions in the header files in the source code, so the compiler is aware of how to compile any function that calls those functions then.

Comment: Yeah that is correct. You specify the calling convention, the compiler generates the corresponding machine code and the processor does the rest.